# Excel: Feeding hundreds of rows and 6 columns to other tab based on column E value?

Tags: excel

First, thank you all for taking the time to help me with these two Excel problems I've encountered while trying to make some magic, your help is greatly appreciated!  This is my first post on S.O. but I've been using this site for a long time as a "Go to" to solve many IT related problems.

I am creating a spreadsheet that lists peoples names, positions, department, and other info, this is done on a worksheet called MASTER TAB. Each additional worksheet filters the data based on what department each person is in.  Example: MASTER TAB lists 300 people, of which 50 people are in Department A, the next worksheet called "Department A" would show all info pertaining to individuals to Department A.  My question how do I do this without using the Filter option?  I've tried Vlookup (only returns 1 value), index, and arrays but I can't quite get it to work.

Here's the link to the spreadsheet to help clear up the mess above.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70KE6LT-M_gMFNoWVY4dGE4QW8/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you all very much for your help!

-Chris

Comment: you might wish to refactor this into smaller more manegable questions that all address a specific problem. That will increasae the probability of people assisting you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment John, once I get the spreadsheet up I think it will be easier to understand.

Comment: Took user comments into consideration, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot your `MASTER TAB` data with `department` for ROWS and Sigma values, then double-click the department count.

Comment: I used PIVOT table but don't like how it changes the format, I would prefer a formula/array that can grab the info from Master TAB and dump it into the yellow worksheet.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Can't use the filter option as it changes the format as well.  I'm looking for an array that could do this.  The reason for being picky is due to the need to have a giant print out for this sheet, the look/format must not change.  Was the downvote really necessary Pnuts?